# how to write query in spring jdbctemplate to fetch multiple rows with any condition?

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

```
select * from  EmployeeDetails where empNo like '%"+searchWord+"%' or Name like '%"+searchWord+"%'"
```

this is my query and this should return multiple rows

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow: But this is not the way it works: Show us what you have tryed! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Simply create `SimpleJDBCTemplate` and query for list similar as below:

```
 private SimpleJdbcTemplate simpleJdbcTemplate = null;

 @Autowired
 public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
     this.simpleJdbcTemplate = new SimpleJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
 }


 List<Employee> employeeList = simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM Employee");
```

And use `org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper` to convert `ResultSet` to your custom object. Here is the links for your reference - 
[Spring JDBC Template](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm)